# Как получить несколько значений объекта?

Tags: javascript

Есть три объекта, обязательное свойство `name` и `surname`. Задача в том, чтобы вывести необязательные свойства.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

```js
function erraySearch(arr) {

  for (var key in arr) {
    if (key != "name" || key != "surname") {
      console.log(key);
    }
  }
}
var a = {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  "age": 18,
}
var b = {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  "fathername": "Семенович",
}
var c = {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  "sex": "мужской",
}
erraySearch(a);
```

Answer (score 4):

Если таких ключей будет чуть больше, полезно создать массив исключений, вместо длинной строки проверок:

```js
let a = {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  age: 18,
  bubu: "moo",
};
search(a);

function search(obj) {
  let dontLook = ["name", "surname"];
  
  for (let key in obj) {
    if ( dontLook.includes(key) ) continue;
     
    console.log(key + ": " + obj[key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы используете `||`(или), в то время как условие должно не быть равным одному `и` в тоже время не быть равным другому.

Вам необходимо использовать оператор `&&`.

```js
function erraySearch(arr) {

  for (var key in arr) {
    if (key != "name" && key != "surname") {
      console.log(key);
    }
  }
}
var a = {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  "age": 18,
};
var b = {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  "fathername": "Семенович",
};
var c = {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
  "sex": "мужской",
};
erraySearch(a);
erraySearch(b);
erraySearch(c);
```